# Changing target framework in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, target-framework

What's the deal with Visual Studio?

I tried importing the Caching App Block and got this message:

> The assembly or one of its dependencies you're are trying to import requires a later version of .NET Framework.

I went to the properties of my application in Visual Studio, but I can't find the dropdown to switch....what's the deal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it....went to "Advanced Compile Options" on Compile Tab.....weird!

Answer (score 6):

I think they make it different for C# project and VB project.

**C# project**

Solution Explorer --> Project --> Properties and on the Application tab you'll see Target Framework.

**VB project**

Project Properties --> Compile --> Advanced Compile Options

Answer (score 2):

It should be on the Application tab in the project's properties. A great article on how Visual Studio 2008 handles framework targeting is *[VS 2008 Multi-Targeting Support](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/20/vs-2008-multi-targeting-support.aspx)*.

Comment: Nothing on the Application Tab for me to change target framework.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2008, the Targeted Framework option was greyed out for me. I had to follow the instructions in article *[How to: Modify the Target Framework and Platform Toolset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff770576.aspx)* to change the Targeted Framework so that two related projects could work together.

Basically you unload the project with the wrong framework, open the project file in Visual Studio as a text file, find the line in the XML that specifies the Targeted Framework and change that to the desired framework. Save the file and reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties of a project (Solution Explorer --> Project --> Properties or Menu Bar --> Project --> Properties) and on the Application tab you'll see Target Framework.

Comment: Dude ~ It's not there. I even restarted VS. Its on "Compile Tab" >  "Advanced Compile Options"